# Calling from JSON table

Tags: json, angularjs

Beginner angular JS question

I have a JSON table with this data:

tickets":[
      [
         "available",
         "101"
      ],
      [
         "available",
         "102"
      ],
      [
         "available",
         "103"
      ],
      [
         "available",
         "104"
      ],
      [
         "available",
         "105"

How can I call just the numbers as part of this array? The full table is call ticket_group

so I'm trying {{ticket_group.tickets[0]}} but its clearly not right

How do I get it so it shows only 101, 102, 103, 104, 105

Comment: Do I need an ng-repeat on the number data?

Comment: please use plunker ? show important code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ticket_group.tickets[0][1]}}`

it is called **two-dimensional array**

Comment: I tried your approach but it only gives me the first value.

Comment: then try this line instead `<div ng-repeat="ticket in ticket_group.tickets">{{ticket[1]}}</div>`

Comment: how can I help your rankings? My lvl isn't 15 rep

Answer (score 0):

In your app controller you can specify http requests, such as JSON files.

```
app.controller('YourController', function($http) {
  $http.get('file.json').success(function(example){
    this.alias = example;
  });
});
```

Note that if your file.json is in a folder include that too (i.e. js/file.json).

Also, "alias" should match your expression variable:

```
var alias = [{
  *expressions*
}];
```